# How to access context after setting up the `framework` in Poise (serenity) for a discord bot?

Tags: rust, discord

I want to access that Context object, also pass it around into different functions.
And use that `ctx` object into the function send_changes_via_bot, which would send the updates to discord's api using `ctx.say()`.

I am also wondering if I am using `rx` right, I was thinking if I would recursively call the function the - `rx` being passed in each call would be different since it's continuously receiving from the `tx` in main. But now I am wondering if the old `rx` will just keep being copied as `rx` doesn't seem like a pointer.

[Link to the GitHub repo](https://github.com/ScrexyScroo/metacat)

```rs
    pub async fn bot(rx: &mpsc::Receiver<Value>) {
        let discord_token = fs::read_to_string("discordtoken.txt")
                               .expect("Issue with token");
        let framework = poise::Framework::builder()
            .options(poise::FrameworkOptions {
                // Macro takes care of ctx and user
                commands: vec![account_age(), set_gdrive_channel(),
                               spawn_watcher()], 
                ..Default::default()
            })
            .token(discord_token)
            .intents(serenity::GatewayIntents::non_privileged())
            .setup(|ctx, _ready, framework| {
                Box::pin(async move {
                    poise::builtins::register_globally(ctx, 
                         &framework.options().commands)
                    .await?;
                    Ok(Data {})
                })
            });

        // * ----------------------------------------------------------------
        // * ----------------------------------------------------------------
        // ! Don't know how to pass context here :(
        send_changes_via_bot(ctx, rx).await;
        // * ----------------------------------------------------------------
        // * ----------------------------------------------------------------

        framework.run().await.unwrap();
    }
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] including a definition of `send_changes_via_bot`, a link is no replacement for a complete question.

Comment: @cafce25 that is the whole code related to the bot itself

Answer (score -1):

This did the trick.

```rust
    let metacat = framework.build().await.expect("Failed to init metacat");

    metacat.client().start().await;

    let global_ctx = &metacat.client().cache_and_http;

    send_changes_via_bot(global_ctx, rx);
```